# PHP/MySQL - How to count number of occurencies

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the structure of my MySQL table.

[image]

I have many results. Many of them have same `Brand` for example many of them have `Brand` - `Orrange`, many of them have `Brand` - `Oddiboss` and `Brand` - `Guma`.

So my question is how can i display them like this:

[image]

I think i have to use `while loop`.

```
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products`");

while($rowi = mysql_fetch_array($r))
        {

        $id = $rowi['id'];
        $Title = $rowi['Title'];
        $Brand = $rowi['Brand'];
        }
```

So with this MySQL quesry i can fetch all the results but i can not group them into 3 results displaying how many occurencies everyone have.

I hope you understand what i need.

Comment: And you really shouldn't be using the mysql_ functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should do it:

```
SELECT Brand, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM products 
GROUP BY Brand
```

It should produce these results:

```
+----------+-------+
| Brand    | count |
+----------+-------+
| Orange   | 23    |
| Oddiboss | 342   |
| Guma     | 2     |
+----------+-------+
```

While [**you really shouldn't be using the MySQL extension**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for accessing the database, here is how you would fetch these results:

```
$r = mysql_query("SELECT Brand, COUNT(*) AS count FROM `products` GROUP BY Brand");   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
    echo $row['Brand'] . ' ' . $row['count'] . "<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Add please the echo result to your answer.

Comment: I need the `echo` result so i can see it.

Comment: @TonyStark - Do you not know how to run the query?

Comment: I do not understand your question

Comment: How can i display the results, should i use while loop ?

Comment: @TonyStark - How are you accessing your database? Which PHP extension, MySQL, MySQLi, PDO?

Comment: I use MySQL for accessing.

Comment: @TonyStark - I updated my answer. Please note that MySQL is deprecated and you really should be using a newer extension to access your database.

Comment: Why i should not use MySQL extension for accessing the database ?

Comment: @TonyStark - I added a link in my answer to explain why you shouldn't be.

Comment: How can i add the `WHERE` statement, for example `WHERE Category='$Cat'` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should group by brand column as below :

```
Select Brand, COUNT(*) AS count FROM products group by Brand
```

Comment: And how can i display them ?

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = SELECT Brand, COUNT(*) AS count FROM products GROUP BY Brand
[...]
echo $row['COUNT(*)'];
```